# Perforce sync by date syntax and use of wildards

Tags: synchronization, perforce

I am trying to check out a Perforce repository as of a certain date. The server is version 2010.1. According to the documents, I should be able to do something like this:

> p4 sync @2001/06/24

However, when I attempt this I get the following error:

```
p4 sync @2014/08/28

p4_xsync: "//my/depot/path/@2014/08/28"

//my/depot/path/@2014/08/28 - no such file(s).
```

When I enter the date directly from the example, I get a different message:

```
//my/depot/path/@2001/06/24 - no file(s) as of that date.
```

Am I doing anything wrong? This seems like a very straightforward operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting the same result as if you tried to run `p4 sync //my/depot/path` - you have to specify some actual files to sync (as opposed to just a depot path).

`p4 sync //my/depot/path/...@2014/08/28` will get you all files under the depot path as of 2014/08/28.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me twice!